# Why doesn't Codeception's PhpBrowser follow a "Reload" header?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth, codeception

This is happening to me in a real [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) project in the [Ion Auth authentication library](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/), but for the sake of clarity, I have reduced it to it's simplest form.

### The script:

I have this one line script located at `http://localhost/~captbaritone/redirect/index.php`:

```
<?php header("Refresh:0;url=https://google.com");¬
```

In my browser, it redirects to Google.com.

### The Test:

To test it I wrote this acceptance test:

```
<?php
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Redirect to Google.com');
$I->amOnPage('/index.php');
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('https://www.google.com/');
```

My `acceptance.suite.yml` looks like this:

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - WebHelper
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost/~captbaritone/redirect/'
```

### The results:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.7.1
Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Acceptance Tests (1) -----------------------------------------
Trying to redirect to google.com (RedirectCept.php)       Fail
---------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 460 ms, Memory: 9.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) Failed to redirect to google.com in RedirectCept.php
Sorry, I couldn't see current url equals "https://www.google.com/":
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'https://www.google.com/'
+'/~captbaritone/redirect/index.php'

Scenario Steps:
2. I see current url equals "https://www.google.com/"
1. I am on page "/index.php"

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

### My Question:

Clearly the PhpBrowser is not obeying the redirect. Changing the redirect to a location header, allows the test to pass, but I don't want to (can't) change my application to fit the test suite.

Is this a bug in Codeception? In PhpBrowser? (I'm not really clear on where one starts and the other begins, or if PhpBrowser is even a separate project.) Or maybe this is a functionality I shouldn't expect from a headless browser?

I should disclose that this is my first time working with a test suite.

Comment: There should be some option to set followRedirect I guess, Please provide links to see this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it's something to do with `Refresh` not being a header in the [official standards](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)? (Whereas, `Location` is.)

Comment: @ahmad Where would that option be? In Codeception?

Comment: @Lefters That sounds like a probable explanation. PhpBrowser didn't implement it because it's non-standard. Do you know where I would go to see if that's an intentional omission or a feature they would be willing to support?

Comment: just came across this issue. Getting a page that says 'Redirecting to...' instead of the page it should be loading, causing my test to fail. 
Has any progress been made on this? THx

Comment: @Adamski I ended up switching to the Web Driver module with Selenium running Phantom JS.

Comment: Thanks @JordanEldredge - I am using PhantomJS with PhpBrowser for functional tests.. will try it out with acceptance tests using selenium / web driver too.

Comment: Still getting this issue also with WebDriver and PhantomJS.. maybe I need Selenium..?

Comment: Realised I did not have the Laravel4 module selected in my acceptance.suite.yml - now it works, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in a Codeception 2.0:

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/625#issuecomment-33281671

I would suggest you upgrade and try again.

Comment: I can't upgrade to 2.x because it requires phpunit 4.x and we're stuck on 3.7 because of some dependencies. :( Is there any other solution that will work with Codeception 1.x?