# Codeception tests failing on redirect with Laravel 4 and PhpBrowser

Tags: testing, laravel-4, codeception

Related to this:[Why doesn't Codeception's PhpBrowser follow a "Reload" header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461630/why-doesnt-codeceptions-phpbrowser-follow-a-reload-header)

I am using Laravel 4.1

I cant get tests to pass that are redirecting to another page, e.g.:

```
$I = new TestGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('be able to log in via the login form');
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('Email','test@student.com');
$I->fillField('Password','password');
$I->click('confirm');

$I->canSee('WELCOME Test Student');
```

Test fails with ' Redirecting to http:// ....' instead of the page it redirects to.

The redirects are being performed by  Redirect::route($name)

Seems to be an issue with PhpBrowser?

Any workarounds? Can't find any recent info with a solution.

Comment: I found a workaround: [link](stackoverflow.com/questions/19461630/why-doesnt-codeceptions-phpbrowser-follow-a-reload-header#comment34871941_19461630)

Using **WebDriver** and **PhantomJS** as the browser in acceptance got it working. Would be good to have functional tests working like this too but this will do for now. Not a full answer so not posting as such.

Comment: what if https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2511 ?